# vertx web server with dual stack support

Tags: webserver, vert.x

We would like to create one webserver that is able to listen on both ipv6/ipv4 address that will be assigned by [k8s on dual stack servers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dual-stack/).
One quick idea is to use the InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() but here we might have Inet4Address and Inet6Adress instances. We could use those two instances and create the two webservers that will perform the same actions using same handlers/routers.
I think that in envoy project, it is possible to create listener on both ipv4/ipv6 addresses [envoy issue 11124](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/11124) but still it is not clear if the envoy internally starts two separate servers.
Is something similar supported on vertx or is it possible to have one webserver that will handle connections from both ipv4/ipv6 addresses?

Currently, we are starting two web servers for ipv4 and ipv6 local addresses respectively but we would like to explore if there are any other ways. Any ideas/proposals would be more than welcome!

Comment: According to the [Networking IPv6 User Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/index.html), _if a socket is bound to an IPv6 anylocal address on a dual-stack machine, it can accept both IPv6 and IPv4 traffic_. Have you tried binding to `::` ?